# Simplifying a complex number divided by a real

Tags: complex-numbers

Is the equality

$$\frac{a+bi}{c} = \frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c}i$$

true for all real $a$, $b$ and $c \neq 0$ ?

Comment: It is also true if $a, b, c$ are any complex numbers with $c \ne 0$ - the fact that they are real has no bearing on the truth of this algebraic identity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that equation is true for all real $a, b$ and $c\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

The usual rules of arithmetic still apply in $\mathbb{C}$. Just about anything you can do in $\mathbb{R}$ you can do in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Just about anything you can do in $\mathbb{R}$ you can do in $\mathbb{C}$....Really?